# How can I use polymorphism in STL List?

Tags: c++, list, stl, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(): data_(0){}
        virtual void print(){
            cout << "no" << endl;
        }
    protected:
        int data_;
};
class B : public A{
    public:
        B(): A(){}
        void print() override{
            cout << data_ << endl;
        }
};


list<A> my;

int main()
{

    B* b = new B();
    b->print();

    my.push_back(*b);
    for (list<A>::iterator i = my.begin(); i != my.end(); i++){
        i->print();
    }

}
```

The result of `b->print` is `0`, but why is the result of `i->print()` `no`?

I want to make `0` come out when I use STL lists and polymorphism. What should I do?

Comment: The direct answer is that to use polymorphism in C++, you need to use a pointer or reference to the actual object. In your case, you'll probably want a list of pointers rather than a list of objects. Most of the time that should probably be some smart pointer class rather than raw pointers. You might also want to look into Boost [ptr_list](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html).

Comment: Thank you! I need to study hard.